# Problems accessing cluster via ssh

Tags: server, ssh, xorg

I am trying to access a cluster via ssh and utilize the X display. I have used both `-Y` and `-X`, but I get the following error: `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.` 
 I've tried `ssh -Y -vvv` to find more information about the problem, and I get the following:

```
debug1: confirm x11
debug3: send packet: type 91
debug2: X11 connection uses different authentication protocol.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

I am trying to use the option `-Y`.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It may be useful to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1164633/edit) the question and add what kind of authentication you are trying to use. Also indicate if `ssh` works without the `-X` or the `-Y` flags.